# Trouble with HWI

Tags: hwi

I have downloaded and installed hardware wallet interface, here is the output that I'm getting from ./hwi.py enumerate:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/./hwi.py", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/_cli.py", line 304, in main
    result = process_commands(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/_cli.py", line 270, in process_commands
    return args.func(args)
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/_cli.py", line 63, in enumerate_handler
    return enumerate(password=args.password, expert=args.expert, chain=args.chain)
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/commands.py", line 117, in enumerate
    result.extend(imported_dev.enumerate(password, expert, chain))
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/devices/trezor.py", line 857, in enumerate
    devs.extend(webusb.WebUsbTransport.enumerate())
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/devices/trezorlib/transport/webusb.py", line 130, in enumerate
    dev.getProduct()
  File "/home/eoin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 2003, in getProduct
    return self.open().getProduct()
  File "/home/eoin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 2055, in open
    mayRaiseUSBError(libusb1.libusb_open(self.device_p, byref(handle)))
  File "/home/eoin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 127, in mayRaiseUSBError
    __raiseUSBError(value)
  File "/home/eoin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 119, in raiseUSBError
    raise __STATUS_TO_EXCEPTION_DICT.get(value, __USBError)(value)
usb1.USBErrorAccess: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS [-3]
```

What is the problem here? It is supposed to tell me the device type and device path, but instead this is what I am getting.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ./hwi.py enumerate` ?

Comment: eoin@eoin-IdeaPad-3-15IAU7:~$ cd HWI
eoin@eoin-IdeaPad-3-15IAU7:~/HWI$ sudo ./hwi.py enumerate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/./hwi.py", line 6, in <module>
    from hwilib._cli import main
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/_cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .commands import (

Comment: File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/commands.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .hwwclient import HardwareWalletClient
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/hwwclient.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .psbt import PSBT
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/psbt.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .tx import (
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/tx.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ._serialize import (
  File "/home/eoin/HWI/hwilib/_serialize.py", line 23, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Protocol
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'

Comment: Seems to be working this morning. How do you retrieve the balance on your hardware wallet? There doesn't seem to be a command for this after using the --help option.